# What is LINQ equivalent of SQL

Tags: c#, linq

```
List<string> li = new List<string>();
        li.Add("10,11,12,1");
        li.Add("10,11,12,13");

        var q = from d in li
                where d.Contains("1")
                select d;
```

I have a list of string with two values. I have single value "1" and I want to fetch that list object which contains value "1" in string i.e. I want first object in list. If I use contains then it will return both list object values, so what will be query which gives me the perfect result?

Comment: I think you are confusing yourself here. What you actually want to do is identify which list contains the value `1` without considering the 1 in `10`, `11` and so on. Nothing to do with LINQ, or lists of items.

Comment: Here is sample code.I have db field which contains comma separated value and I match single value with this field.If I get that value in field values then it will return true else false

Answer (score 5):

Try changing the where to

```
where d.Split(',').Contains("1")
```

This will split the string into a list of items, and then check if the item is in that list.

**EDIT:**

As mentioned in the comments, you do not need the `ToList()` so changethe above.

Comment: It splits the strings by ",", and then you check that array/list (["10","11","12","1"], ["10,"11","12","13"]) for "1", which should match the 1st string.

Comment: But after splitting the array string value "10" also contains "1" then  how is it perfectly match??

Comment: That Contains works against the array, not the string. Basically if the array has an element "1"

Comment: This will create a bunch of unnecessary strings.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run this query directly against database, you'll have to do something like this:

```
 var q = from d in li
            where d.StartsWith("1,") || d.EndsWith(",1") || d.Contains(",1,") 
             || d.Equals("1")
            select d;
```

Otherwise the other answer works in memory

Comment: if db field contains single value without comma separate then what will be the answer??

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
List<string> li = new List<string>();
li.Add("10,11,12,1");
li.Add("10,11,12,13");
string searchItem = "1";
var q = from d in li
        where ("," + d + ",").Contains("," + searchItem + ",")
        select d;
```

and this query will also work for directly against database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var q =
    from d in li
    where d.Split(',').Any(x => x == "1")
    select d;
```

Comment: This will create a bunch of unnecessary strings.

Comment: @PauloMorgado - But not a significant amount that's worth worrying about. The terseness and readability of the code outweighs any inefficiency, don't you think?

Comment: @PauloMorgado - Did you seriously down vote based on your comment?

Comment: Do you really think believe in what you wrote in your comment? The OP says nothing about the amount of data or the executing environment. What makes you think this wouldn't kill the system?

Comment: @PauloMorgado - What makes you think it would? I just ran a test on 100,000 lines of 100 numbers per line. Creating the data used 79MB of memory. Running the above query took 46.5kB. Yes kilo-bytes. And it ran 127 generation 0 garbage collections and took 1.3 seconds. This query is no where near causing the machine to fall over.

Comment: Upvoted. This is much better than the answer that was upvoted twice in terms of readability and maintainability. And I'm pretty sure the most upvoted answer creates the same amount of strings? I've been downvoted before by someone who couldn't believe my answer ran as fast as it did. It was pretty frustrating.